# How does Combine know an ObservableObject actually changed

Tags: swift, combine

The `ObservableObject` protocol defined by the Combine framework has an `objectWillChange` publisher property that lets you know when the properties of this object *will* change, meaning that, if subscribers to this publisher were to read its value when they get this will change event, they will still read the value *before* it is changed, what I am trying to understand is:

- How do frameworks like SwiftUI know that the value actually **did** change (ie: how do they get the new value) when it seems the only event you can subscribe to is the *will change* one? Is the underlying mechanism a publicly available API in the Combine framework?
- How to get the actual new value of an `ObservableObject` after you received the will change event?

Answer (score 22):

SwiftUI doesn't know if the `ObservableObject` *actually* changed. SwiftUI trusts you. If you tell it the object will change (by making `objectWillChange` emit an output), then SwiftUI assumes that the object changes, and schedules a display update.

I'm not 100% sure why Apple chose `objectWillChange` as the signal. At WWDC 2019, the property was in fact `didChange`, not `objectWillChange`. They changed it while Xcode 11 was still in beta. Perhaps what they do is grab the object's state when `objectWillChange` emits, and then later they grab it again when it's time to update the screen, and they somehow compare the values.

As to how to get the object's value after `objectWillChange` emits, that's up to you. They way SwiftUI does it is by registering a [`CFRunLoopObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfrunloopobserver) for the [`.beforeWaiting`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfrunloopactivity/kcfrunloopbeforewaiting) activity. When the observer runs, it re-renders any views whose `ObservableObject`s have signaled.

Note that if you use a `@Published` property to store the value in your `ObservableObject`, then you can subscribe to the property's own publisher by using the `$` prefix. For example:

```
class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Int = 0
}

let object = MyObject()
let ticket = object.$value
    .sink { print("new value: \($0); old value: \(object.value)") }

object.value = 1
```

The `Published` wrapper publishes the current value when you subcribe, and then publishes the new value each time it changes. But note that it publishes the new value **before** storing it, as the example code above demonstrates with the following output:

```
new value: 0; old value: 0
new value: 1; old value: 0
```

Comment: What happens if I call objectWillChange() and then change the underlying value 1 second later? 1 minute later? Does SwiftUI stop listening to the promised object update after some time?

Comment: As I said, SwiftUI registers a run loop observer to act on the changed value. So you must change the value before that observer runs. That means you must change the value before returning control to the main run loop. That means, effectively, that you should make the change immediately after firing `objectWillChange`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020-10040/?time=1003
WWDC2020, Apple says, the reason we use "will", "One of the questions that we often get is "why 'will' change? Why not 'did' change?" And the reason is that SwiftUI needs to know when something is about to change so it can coalesce every change into a single update."

Comment: That reason given by Apple is bogus. You can coalesce updates regardless of whether you're informed of the change before or after it occurs. As far as I can tell, the only reason to be informed **before** the change is if you want to compare the “before” and “after” values—which is not the same as coalescing.

Answer (score 5):

What I did was add to each ObservableObject that I needed to know **after** changes of

```
public var objectDidChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
```

That you can subscribe to and you manually call `.send()` on after everything has changed.

Answer (score 4):

This situation cropped up for me when I was trying to update UIKit in response to `@Pubished` properties on an `ObservedObject` being updated. In SwiftUI this is done for you via `@ObservedObject` but in UIKit we have to do it ourselves. You could observer each published property manually but thats annoying.

I haven't exhaustively tested this yet but it appears to work for my use case.

```
final class MyObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    var objectDidChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        self.objectWillChange
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main) // basically converts this to a an `objectDidChange` publisher!
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And my VC,

```
public final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let object = MyObservableObject()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        object
            .objectDidChange
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in self?.updateUI() })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI listens for `ObservableObject` events via `@ObservedObject` wrapper

> ```
> /// A dynamic view property that subscribes to a `ObservableObject` automatically invalidating the view
> /// when it changes.
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> @propertyWrapper public struct ObservedObject<ObjectType> : DynamicProperty where ObjectType : ObservableObject {
> ```

which is as seem `DynamicProperty`, and here is what they said about it

> ```
> /// Represents a stored variable in a `View` type that is dynamically
> /// updated from some external property of the view. These variables
> /// will be given valid values immediately before `body()` is called.
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> public protocol DynamicProperty {
>
>     /// Called immediately before the view's body() function is
>     /// executed, after updating the values of any dynamic properties
>     /// stored in `self`.
>     mutating func update()
> }
> ```

so, `ObservedObject` wrapper listens for published events from `ObservableObject` and once `update()` is called provides latest value (most probably directly re-cache for it, if needed, in place of update call).

Comment: Thank you, while I see how SwiftUI knows a property is an ObservableObject, I don't understand by which mechanism it knows when the properties of the observed object have "truly" changed. What I mean is that it knows the properties *will* change, but then, lets say the value only changes one second after it emitted the will change event, what does SwiftUI do during this time? Does it actively wait for a change? Does it simply except the properties change to occur on the main thread, at the next run loop iteration?

Comment: Why so complicated? As for me it is enough to clean previously cached value (as onWill called synchronously), so on the next redraw iteration (which happens asynchronously) during call of update() just get new value. At least I would do it in that way.... how it is done really nows only Apple, because it is proprietary code. ))

Answer (score 2):

According to WWDC 2021 [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=361):

> In SwiftUI, ObservableObjects can interact with the SwiftUI run loop
> in some interesting ways. Let’s go back to the Photos ObservableObject
> and look at the updateItems method. I’m going to call updateItems from
> my SwiftUI views and it will run on the main actor. Let’s use this
> blue rectangle to show the time when updateItems is running. I want to
> focus on this line of code where I assign the fetched photos to my
> “items” property. Because “items” is a Published property, this
> assignment triggers an objectWillChange event, immediately followed by
> writing the fetched photos to the storage for “items.” When SwiftUI
> sees this objectWillChange, it takes a snapshot of my items. On the
> next tick of the run loop after the snapshot, SwiftUI compares the
> snapshot to the current value. Because these values are different,
> SwiftUI knows to update my views that depend on Photos. Note that
> because objectWillChange, updating the storage, and the run loop tick
> all happen on the main actor, they’re guaranteed to happen in order.

1. `objectWillChange` notifies SwiftUI to create a snapshot of the current state in the current runloop.
2. `objectDidChange` to set the value in the current runloop immediately following will change notification
3. In the next runloop, swiftUI will compare the current value with the snapshot in the previous runloop to determine if it updates the UI or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On this point:

> - How to get the actual new value of an ObservableObject after you received the will change event?

This can be achieved by moving the `@Published` attribute to a (dummy) property that is updated later. For example, maybe you have an `ObservableObject` with a published property like this:

```swift
@Published private var myInterestingValue: MyEnum = .unset

// Read-only accessor for the interesting value
var theInterestingValue: MyEnum {
    myInterestingValue
}

// Some function in the class that updates the value
private func changeValue {
    myInterestingValue = .aNewValue
}
```

The example above shows the normal way to publish updates, using a read-only accessor to allow observers to read but not update the property. However, as you point out, observers get notified before the property takes on the new value, at which time the read-only accessor still delivers the old value. So let's do it another way:

```swift
// A dummy counter, used to publish updates
@Published private var nUpdates = 0

// myInterestingValue is no longer published.
// Instead, a setter observer has been added
private var myInterestingValue: MyEnum = .unset {

    // After a value has been set, publish an update
    didSet { nUpdates += 1 }
}

// The read-only accessor and updating function can
// be implemented in exactly the same way as before
```

Here, the property of interest is updated and accessed in exactly the same way, but observers are notified by virtue of the dummy counter being updated in the setter observer. This happens *after* the property has been updated, so the read-only accessor will now deliver the new value of the property.