# SwiftUI: How wrong is to call the objectWillChange.send() after the change in the model data happened?

Tags: swiftui, observableobject, observedobject

I'm trying to better understand the mechanism how SwiftUI gets notified about changes in observed data and invalidates UI.

In particular, I wonder if something won't work correctly (e.g. animations?) when `objectWillChange.send()` is called on `ObservableObject` **after** the underlying data model have changed, and more importantly **why** is that.

If it doesn't matter when the synthesized publisher notifies its observers after the change, then why is it named `objectWillChange` and not `objectDidChange`?

Let's say I have a view model like this the following and it observes changes in some model via a delegate method (the code is simplified for the example purposes):

```
protocol ModelDelegate: AnyObject {
    func modelDidChange() {
}

class Model {

  weak var delegate: ModelDelegate?

  var stroredString: String {
    didSet { self.delegate?.modelDidChange() }
  }

}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

  private let model: Model = Model(delegate: self)

  var calculatedProperty: String { model.storedString }

}

extension ViewModel: ModelDelegate {

  func modelDidChange() {
    // we get called when the change has already happened.
    // is it wrong to publish the change via objectWillChange?
    self.objectWillChange.send()
  }
}
```

And then the View looks like this:

```
struct MyView: View {

  @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View {
    Text(self.viewModel.calculatedProperty)
  }
}
```

## Question

Can I expect that something's not going to work correctly when `objectWillChange.send()` is called on `ObservableObject` **after** the underlying data model have changed? If yes, in which case and more importantly, **why** is that?

If it doesn't matter when the synthesized publisher notifies its observers after the change, then why is it named `objectWillChange` and not `objectDidChange`?

Comment: You shouldn't expect any issues, there is no reason to think there would be issues.

Comment: It is named `objectWillChange` simply because the `Published` protocol triggers from the [`willSet` block](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published).  For an exhaustive discussion, see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519530/how-does-combine-know-an-observableobject-actually-changed/61675243#61675243)